# Case-insensitive with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am desperately looking for a way to give a String and make it `case-insensitive`, and get the result with `MongoDB`.
I tried with a `RegEx`, but it doesn't work properly, because if the given String has some characters, they can conflict with the `RegEx`.

I saw that MongoDB allows to do this, but without RegEx, which seems better, with `$caseSensitive`, except that I don't understand how this works.

Can you help me please?

What I used to do:

```
const user = await userModel.findOne({ Name: new RegExp("\\b" + request.username.toString().trim() + "\\b", "i"), Password: hash });
```

Thank you in advance for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Best option is to  create case insesitive  [index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-case-insensitive/)

Example:

```
   db.collection.createIndex( { Name: 1},
                  { collation: { locale: 'en', strength: 2 } } )
```

And search insensitive as follow:

```
 db.collection.find( { Name: "JohN" } ).collation( { locale: 'en', strength: 2 } )
```

Will find: John,joHn,JOHN etc.

Comment: Thank you @R2D2, it works very well! Else, how can I do to to search for a user with a name that starts with a String? Like with startsWithin JS. I would really like to not use RegEx for this too, what you told me sounded great.

Comment: You have in general three options , you can use $where to add any javascript function you like: db.collection.find( { $where: "this.Name.toLowerCase().indexOf('j') >= 0" } ); or you can use regex with the index like: db.collection.find({"Name" : { $regex : /^J/ }}).hint({"Name" : 1})  or use aggregation like db.collection.aggregate([{$match: 
    {$expr: { $gt: [{ $indexOfCP: [ "$Name", "J" ] }, -1]}}}])

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make use of $regex with i as option, just like this , read more here [Mongo Documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/mongodb/schema-design-anti-pattern-case-insensitive-query-index/)

```
const user = await userModel.findOne({ Name :{regex:/request.username.toString().trim()/i}, Password: hash });
```

It should work fine!

Comment: `request.username.toString().trim()` return a String, and I can't use it like this, so why I have used `new RegEx()`.